# How to add in else statement in underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have the following code:

```
var c = 'Credits: <% if (credits) { %> <%= credits %> <% } %> <% else  { %> N/A <% } %>'
```

However I get `Unexpected token else`. Is the `else` statement different than how the `if` statement is added? What should the above correctly be?

Comment: A quick `t = _.template(tmpl); console.log(t.source)` might be enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the `%> <%` between `}` and `else`. Like this:

```
var c = 'Credits: <% if (credits) { %> <%= credits %> <% } else { %> N/A <% } %>';
```

Alternatively, the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is one of my faves:

```
var c = 'Credits: <%= credits ? credits : "N/A" %>';
```

In case it's unclear, the ternary is basically a reduced if/else statement. The part before the `?` is the expression being evaluated for truthiness. If it's truthy, the middle part between `?` and `:` is executed, but if it's falsey, the last part after `:` is executed instead.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be with the `OR` operator:

```
var c = 'Credits:</b> <%= credits || "No credits" %></div>
```

Comment: Question is *"How to add in else statement in underscore template*, and this doesn't answer the question... this is better suited as an update in question,  or a comment